# Los controles Dropdown List no muestra el icono

Tags: .net-core, html-select

amigos.

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto Net Core 5.0, pero al crear los DropdownList, no me muestra el icono.

Este es un fragmento del codigo conde creo uno de los DropDownList

```
<label asp-for="StatusOCId" class="control-label">Estatus OC</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusOCId, ViewBag.StatusOCList as SelectList, new {@class = "form-control"} )
<span asp-validation-for="StatusOCId" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Pero como podrán ver en la imagen, no se muestra el icono que es como una "v".
¿Alguna solucion para esto?, gracias de antemano.

[image: controles Dropdown no muestran icono]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en la clase del

```
<label asp-for="StatusOCId" class="control-label">Estatus OC</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusOCId, ViewBag.StatusOCList as SelectList, new {@class = "form-select"} )
<span asp-validation-for="StatusOCId" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Yo lo tenia como "form-control" y es "form-select", de cualquier forma, gracias a quien leyo mi pregunta.